# Do we have a Salesforces global database for all clients that installed my package?

Tags: custom-object, database

Please help me with this question and please correct me if I misunderstand anything.

I am developing a package, in this package, I created some custom objects. I also have my external Web Service and my external database. Please take a look at my picture for more details:
[image: Application structure]

As I imagined, when clients install my package from App Exchange, the custom objects will be added to clients side, so they have their own database. The content of custom objects in each clients will be different. Is it correct or not?

And another question: Do I have some kind of "global Salesforce database" (stored in custom objects) but all clients will see it?

Thank you very much for your time!
Phu Nguyen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably read this [The Force.com Multitenant Architecture: Understanding the Design of Salesforce.com’s Internet Application
Development Platform](http://www.developerforce.com/media/ForcedotcomBookLibrary/Force.com_Multitenancy_WP_101508.pdf).

To answer your specific questions:

- Your package is installed into an "org" and all orgs are isolated from each other. So users working with your package in one org will never see data added by users in another org. A business will typically have a single org but may have thousands of users all working in that org and so sharing data.
- There is no global database. There is the [License Management App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/lma_overview.htm) that you can add to your own sales org to track where your package is installed and its licensing.